# MySQL: не получается добавить в запрос уловие, включающее в себя результат подзапроса

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    is_online,
    adate,
    photo,
    rdate,
    (
        select count(*)
        from instance2_interests_users b
        where b.uid = a.id and b.`is_deleted` = 0
    ) as fg

FROM `instance24_users` a

WHERE fg > 0 and a.`is_deleted` = 0 

ORDER BY `rdate` asc
```

Почему появляется данная ошибка?

```
Unknown column 'fg' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***fg*** на данном уровне не определен.

Вам нужно использовать оператор [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Я бы переписал запрос так:

```
SELECT

id, firstname, lastname, is_online, adate, photo, rdate, count(b.id) as fg

FROM `instance24_users` as a

LEFT JOIN instance2_interests_users as b
ON (b.uid = a.id and b.`is_deleted` = 0)

WHERE a.`is_deleted` = 0

GROUP BY id, firstname, lastname, is_online, adate, photo, rdate
HAVING count(b.id) > 0

ORDER BY `rdate` asc
```

Извините, нет под рукой ничего, чтобы проверить валидность запроса. Могут быть опечатки.

Comment: Однако, работает после некоторых изменений.